# Selenium UI Test Fails When Running On VS Test, But Runs In Visual Studio Locally Fine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our QA analyst wrote UI Test using these Nuget Packages

- NUnit 3.8.1
- NUnit Console Runner 3.7.0
- Nunit 3 Test Adapter 3.8.0
- Nunit Orange 2.1.0
- Selenium Support 3.5.2
- Selenium Web Driver 3.5.2
- Selenium Web Driver IEDriver 3.5.1
- Selenium Web Driver Wait Extensions 1.0.0

When we open the solution in visual studio and select the test category to run, each test opens a firefox browser, login, navigate to the page, detect the element and basically passes.

However, when we use Visual Studio's scripted builds, on the Visual Studio Test V2 process, all test fails with this error:

```
Failed   Test A
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z Error Message:
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : 
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z Stack Trace:
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at x.Init.click(By locator) in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\x\Init\Init.cs:line 362
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at x.AbstractPage.expandMenuItem(By menuItemlocator) in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\xSelenium\Pages\AbstractPage.cs:line 223
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at xSelenium.AbstractPage.openAirlinesPage() in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\xSelenium\Pages\AbstractPage.cs:line 775
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    at xSelenium.Acceptance.Acceptance_SeniorManager_OpenAndCheckLinksOnAirlinesPage() in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\xSelenium\Tests\Acceptance.cs:line 750Standard Output Messages:
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 25 seconds
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at xSelenium.Init.waitUntilElementIsNotVisible(By by) in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\xSelenium\Init\Init.cs:line 596
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    Unable to locate element: //span[text()='OK']
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    *Start of error stack trace*
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z       at xSelenium.Init.isElementPresent(By by) in E:\agent\_work\1\s\UI Tests\AutomatedTests(FF)\xSelenium\Init\Init.cs:line 412
2017-09-06T19:09:01.3495462Z    *End of error stack trace*
```

The build machine is running Windows 10 (another build machine runs Server 2012, and throws same error)

- Firefox 55
- Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113

These Visual Studio Test options have been enabled:

- Test Mix contains UI tests

The agent on the server is on interactive mode and is registered as a Windows Service - it has 'Allow service to interact with desktop' enabled.

Have increased the SetPageLoadTimeout and SetScriptTimeout timeout to 120s but problem still persist.

Comment: Share the detail log on the OneDrive. On the other hand, try to setup the build agent with interactive mode directly (not the service with Allow service to interact with desktop option). https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running functional tests, you typically need to use the [Run Functional Tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium#include-the-test-in-a-ci-build) task to run on a test agent.